# Python - Creating list of week numbers of months using dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a start date ('2019-11-18') and an end date ('2021-02-19'). I am trying to create a list of all the weeks of each month that exist between the start and end date. My expected result should be something like this:

```
list = ['2019.Nov.3','2019.Nov.4', '2019.Nov.5' .... '2021.Feb.2','2021.Feb.3']
```

If the first or last date of a month lands on a Wednesday, i will assume that the week belongs to this month (As 3 out of the 5 working days will belong to this month)

I was actually successful in creating a dataframe with all the weeks of the year that exist between the start and end date using the following code:

```
date_1 = '18-11-19'

first_date = datetime.strptime(date_1, '%d-%m-%y')

date_2 = '19-02-21'

last_date = datetime.strptime(date_2, '%d-%m-%y')

timeline = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Week'])


def create_list(df):
    start_year = int(first_date.isocalendar()[0])
    start_week = int(first_date.isocalendar()[1])
    end_year = int(last_date.isocalendar()[0])
    end_week = int(last_date.isocalendar()[1])

    while start_year < (end_year + 1):

        if start_year == end_year:

            while start_week < (end_week + 1):

                if len(str(start_week)) == 1:

                    week = f'{start_year}' + '.0' + f'{start_week}'

                else:

                    week = f'{start_year}' + '.' + f'{start_week}'

                df = df.append(({'Year': start_year, 'Week': week}), ignore_index=True)
                start_week += 1

        else:

            while start_week < 53:

                if len(str(start_week)) == 1:

                    week = f'{start_year}' + '.0' + f'{start_week}'

                else:

                    week = f'{start_year}' + '.' + f'{start_week}'

                df = df.append(({'Year': start_year, 'Week': week}), ignore_index=True)
                start_week += 1

        start_year += 1
        start_week = 1

    return df


timeline = create_list(timeline)
```

I was successfully able to use this as an x axis for my line graph. However, the axis is a bit hard to read and its very difficult to know which week belongs to which month.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me a hand with this!

Edit:

So here is the solution with the guidance of @Serge Ballesta. I hope it helps anyone who might need something similiar in the future!

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.relativedelta
from datetime import datetime


def year_week(date):
    if len(str(date.isocalendar()[1])) == 1:

        return f'{date.isocalendar()[0]}' + '.0' + f'{date.isocalendar()[1]}'

    else:

        return f'{date.isocalendar()[0]}' + '.' + f'{date.isocalendar()[1]}'


date_1 = '18-11-19'

first_date = datetime.strptime(date_1, '%d-%m-%y')

date_2 = '19-02-21'

last_date = datetime.strptime(date_2, '%d-%m-%y')

set_first_date = str((first_date - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).date())

set_last_date = str((last_date + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).date())

s = pd.date_range(set_first_date, set_last_date, freq='W-WED'
                  ).to_series(name='wed').reset_index(drop=True)

df = s.to_frame()

df['week'] = df.apply(lambda x: year_week(x['wed']), axis=1)

df = df.assign(week_of_month=s.groupby(s.dt.strftime('%Y%m')
                                       ).cumcount() + 1)

df = df[(s >= pd.Timestamp('2019-11-18'))
        & (s <= pd.Timestamp('2021-02-19'))]

df['month_week'] = (df['wed'].dt.strftime('%Y.%b.') + df['week_of_month'].astype(str)).tolist()

df = df.drop(['wed', 'week_of_month'], axis = 1)

print (df)
```

Printed df:

```
       week  month_week
4   2019.47  2019.Nov.3
5   2019.48  2019.Nov.4
6   2019.49  2019.Dec.1
7   2019.50  2019.Dec.2
8   2019.51  2019.Dec.3
..      ...         ...
65  2021.03  2021.Jan.3
66  2021.04  2021.Jan.4
67  2021.05  2021.Feb.1
68  2021.06  2021.Feb.2
69  2021.07  2021.Feb.3
```

Comment: It seems then that your question is how to display it nicely on a graph, not how to create the data? Please show the code where you create the graph.

Comment: Hello @blueteeth, i plot the graph using powerbi, that is why it would be useful to have it as a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build a Series of timestamps with a frequency of `W-WED` to have consistently Wednesday as day of week. That way, we immediately get the correct month for the week.

To have the number of the week in the month, I would start one month before the required start, and use a `cumcount` on year-month + 1. Then it would be enough to filter only the expected range and properly format the values:

```
# produce a series of wednesdays starting in 2019-10-01
s = pd.date_range('2019-10-01', '2021-03-31', freq='W-WED'
                  ).to_series(name='wed').reset_index(drop=True)

# compute the week number in the month
df = s.to_frame().assign(week_of_month=s.groupby(s.dt.strftime('%Y%m')
                                                 ).cumcount() + 1)

# filter the required range
df = df[(s >= pd.Timestamp('2019-11-18'))
      & (s <= pd.Timestamp('2021-02-19'))]

# here is the expected list
lst = (df['wed'].dt.strftime('%Y.%b.')+df['week_of_month'].astype(str)).tolist()
```

`lst` is as expected:

```
['2019.Nov.3', '2019.Nov.4', '2019.Dec.1', '2019.Dec.2', '2019.Dec.3', '2019.Dec.4', 
'2020.Jan.1', '2020.Jan.2', '2020.Jan.3', '2020.Jan.4', '2020.Jan.5', '2020.Feb.1',
'2020.Feb.2', '2020.Feb.3', '2020.Feb.4', '2020.Mar.1', '2020.Mar.2', '2020.Mar.3',
'2020.Mar.4', '2020.Apr.1', '2020.Apr.2', '2020.Apr.3', '2020.Apr.4', '2020.Apr.5',
'2020.May.1', '2020.May.2', '2020.May.3', '2020.May.4', '2020.Jun.1', '2020.Jun.2',
'2020.Jun.3', '2020.Jun.4', '2020.Jul.1', '2020.Jul.2', '2020.Jul.3', '2020.Jul.4',
'2020.Jul.5', '2020.Aug.1', '2020.Aug.2', '2020.Aug.3', '2020.Aug.4', '2020.Sep.1',
'2020.Sep.2', '2020.Sep.3', '2020.Sep.4', '2020.Sep.5', '2020.Oct.1', '2020.Oct.2',
'2020.Oct.3', '2020.Oct.4', '2020.Nov.1', '2020.Nov.2', '2020.Nov.3', '2020.Nov.4',
'2020.Dec.1', '2020.Dec.2', '2020.Dec.3', '2020.Dec.4', '2020.Dec.5', '2021.Jan.1',
'2021.Jan.2', '2021.Jan.3', '2021.Jan.4', '2021.Feb.1', '2021.Feb.2', '2021.Feb.3']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Works like a charm!

Comment: Although i dont know why your list generates 66 values and my year.week generator generates 65 values. I expected them both to generate the same number of values. Any thoughts on why that might be??

Comment: @dodoelhos: that could be a border problem: I accept one week that you reject...

Comment: I managed to solve it by add a little bit in my code, check my edit it in my question

Answer (score 2):

This may not give you exactly what you need (because of 3 out of 5 days in the last week condition), but may be you can get an idea on how to tweak it to get your desired result.

You can export column `res` to list with `df['res'].to_list()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2019-11-18','2021-02-19', freq=pd.offsets.Week(weekday=0))})
df['year_wk']= df.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%W")).astype(int)
df['mon_beg_wk']= df.date.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp().dt.strftime("%W").astype(int)
df['mon_wk']= df['year_wk']-df['mon_beg_wk']
df['res']= df['date'].dt.strftime("%Y.%b")+'.'+df['mon_wk'].astype(str)
df
```

**Output**

```
    date    year_wk mon_beg_wk  mon_wk  res
0   2019-11-18  46  43  3   2019.Nov.3
1   2019-11-25  47  43  4   2019.Nov.4
2   2019-12-02  48  47  1   2019.Dec.1
3   2019-12-09  49  47  2   2019.Dec.2
4   2019-12-16  50  47  3   2019.Dec.3
5   2019-12-23  51  47  4   2019.Dec.4
6   2019-12-30  52  47  5   2019.Dec.5
7   2020-01-06  1   0   1   2020.Jan.1
8   2020-01-13  2   0   2   2020.Jan.2
9   2020-01-20  3   0   3   2020.Jan.3
10  2020-01-27  4   0   4   2020.Jan.4
11  2020-02-03  5   4   1   2020.Feb.1
12  2020-02-10  6   4   2   2020.Feb.2
13  2020-02-17  7   4   3   2020.Feb.3
14  2020-02-24  8   4   4   2020.Feb.4
15  2020-03-02  9   8   1   2020.Mar.1
16  2020-03-09  10  8   2   2020.Mar.2
17  2020-03-16  11  8   3   2020.Mar.3
18  2020-03-23  12  8   4   2020.Mar.4
19  2020-03-30  13  8   5   2020.Mar.5
20  2020-04-06  14  13  1   2020.Apr.1
21  2020-04-13  15  13  2   2020.Apr.2
22  2020-04-20  16  13  3   2020.Apr.3
23  2020-04-27  17  13  4   2020.Apr.4
24  2020-05-04  18  17  1   2020.May.1
25  2020-05-11  19  17  2   2020.May.2
26  2020-05-18  20  17  3   2020.May.3
27  2020-05-25  21  17  4   2020.May.4
28  2020-06-01  22  22  0   2020.Jun.0
29  2020-06-08  23  22  1   2020.Jun.1
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
36  2020-07-27  30  26  4   2020.Jul.4
37  2020-08-03  31  30  1   2020.Aug.1
38  2020-08-10  32  30  2   2020.Aug.2
39  2020-08-17  33  30  3   2020.Aug.3
40  2020-08-24  34  30  4   2020.Aug.4
41  2020-08-31  35  30  5   2020.Aug.5
42  2020-09-07  36  35  1   2020.Sep.1
43  2020-09-14  37  35  2   2020.Sep.2
44  2020-09-21  38  35  3   2020.Sep.3
45  2020-09-28  39  35  4   2020.Sep.4
46  2020-10-05  40  39  1   2020.Oct.1
47  2020-10-12  41  39  2   2020.Oct.2
48  2020-10-19  42  39  3   2020.Oct.3
49  2020-10-26  43  39  4   2020.Oct.4
50  2020-11-02  44  43  1   2020.Nov.1
51  2020-11-09  45  43  2   2020.Nov.2
52  2020-11-16  46  43  3   2020.Nov.3
53  2020-11-23  47  43  4   2020.Nov.4
54  2020-11-30  48  43  5   2020.Nov.5
55  2020-12-07  49  48  1   2020.Dec.1
56  2020-12-14  50  48  2   2020.Dec.2
57  2020-12-21  51  48  3   2020.Dec.3
58  2020-12-28  52  48  4   2020.Dec.4
59  2021-01-04  1   0   1   2021.Jan.1
60  2021-01-11  2   0   2   2021.Jan.2
61  2021-01-18  3   0   3   2021.Jan.3
62  2021-01-25  4   0   4   2021.Jan.4
63  2021-02-01  5   5   0   2021.Feb.0
64  2021-02-08  6   5   1   2021.Feb.1
65  2021-02-15  7   5   2   2021.Feb.2
```

Comment: OP needs week number of month, not day

Comment: I misunderstood then. Answer modified to get closer to what OP is looking for. The "3 out of 5 days in the last week condition" is tricky though

Comment: Thank you very much @moys! I would like to accept it as an answer but Serge's answer gives exactly what i am looking for

Comment: No issues. We are all learning & helping eachother here, so acceptance is not the final goal :-)

Comment: @moys :D really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I used `datetime.timedelta` to do this. It is supposed to work for all start and end dates.

```
import datetime
import math
date_1 = '18-11-19'

first_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_1, '%d-%m-%y')

date_2 = '19-02-21'


last_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_2, '%d-%m-%y')

start_week_m=math.ceil(int(first_date.strftime("%d"))/7)#Week number of first month
daysTill_nextWeek=7-int(first_date.strftime("%w"))#Number of days to next sunday.

date_template='%Y.%b.'
tempdate=first_date
weeks=['%s%d' % (tempdate.strftime(date_template),start_week_m)]
tempdate=tempdate+datetime.timedelta(days=daysTill_nextWeek)#tempdate becomes the next sunday
while tempdate < last_date:
    temp_year,temp_month=int(tempdate.strftime("%Y")),int(tempdate.strftime("%m"))
    print(start_week_m)
    weeks.append('%s%d' % (tempdate.strftime(date_template),start_week_m+1))
    start_week_m+=1
    tempdate=tempdate+datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    if temp_month != int(tempdate.strftime("%m")):
        print(temp_year,int(tempdate.strftime("%Y")))
        start_week_m=0
print(weeks)
```

prints

```
['2019.Nov.3', '2019.Nov.4', '2019.Dec.1', '2019.Dec.2', '2019.Dec.3', '2019.Dec.4', '2019.Dec.5', '2020.Jan.1', '2020.Jan.2', '2020.Jan.3', '2020.Jan.4', '2020.Feb.1', '2020.Feb.2', '2020.Feb.3', '2020.Feb.4', '2020.Mar.1', '2020.Mar.2', '2020.Mar.3', '2020.Mar.4', '2020.Mar.5', '2020.Apr.1', '2020.Apr.2', '2020.Apr.3', '2020.Apr.4', '2020.May.1', '2020.May.2', '2020.May.3', '2020.May.4', '2020.May.5', '2020.Jun.1', '2020.Jun.2', '2020.Jun.3', '2020.Jun.4', '2020.Jul.1', '2020.Jul.2', '2020.Jul.3', '2020.Jul.4', '2020.Aug.1', '2020.Aug.2', '2020.Aug.3', '2020.Aug.4', '2020.Aug.5', '2020.Sep.1', '2020.Sep.2', '2020.Sep.3', '2020.Sep.4', '2020.Oct.1', '2020.Oct.2', '2020.Oct.3', '2020.Oct.4', '2020.Nov.1', '2020.Nov.2', '2020.Nov.3', '2020.Nov.4', '2020.Nov.5', '2020.Dec.1', '2020.Dec.2', '2020.Dec.3', '2020.Dec.4', '2021.Jan.1', '2021.Jan.2', '2021.Jan.3', '2021.Jan.4', '2021.Jan.5', '2021.Feb.1', '2021.Feb.2']
```

Comment: Thank you @fruitbat! I like the logic behind this